# arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc equivalent for other Android targets

Tags: android, linux, gcc, android-ndk, cross-compiling

I have a C program I cross-compile successfully for Android on Linux using

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -static
```

Which are the other command line cross compilers for the other Android targets (*mips, x86, arm64-v8am, armeabi-v7a, mips64, x86_64*)?

I know I could use ndk-build with

```
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE) LOCAL_LDFLAGS := -static
```

but for some reason it compiles fine but the executable doesn't work.

Comment: Look in the toolchains folder of your NDK installation (but note that armeabi and armeabi-v7a uses the same toolchain).

Comment: I've tried arm-linux-androideabi-gcc in the toolchains folder but I get some include errors, how can I indicate where are the proper headers at command line?

Comment: Add the appropriate directories [to the include search path](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html)